# implementation of atom_add function on non-integers in openCL, devices with older compute capability

Tags: c++, opencl

I want to use atomic functions on device memory with non-integer numbers (float and double), for instance I saw in the **CUDA C Programming Guide** the next code for implement `atomicAdd` function for double-precision floating-point numbers:

code extracted from [CUDA C Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/8.0/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions):

---

```
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 600
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                              (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;

    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                        __double_as_longlong(val +
                               __longlong_as_double(assumed)));

    // Note: uses integer comparison to avoid hang in case of NaN (since NaN != NaN)
    } while (assumed != old);

    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
#endif
```

Is it possible to do something similar in openCL?, I have a device with compute capability 2.1

**UPD**

---

I managed to write an equivalent to the original code that seems to work:

```
double atom_add_double(__global double* address, double val) {
    __global long* address_as_ull =
        (__global long*)address;
    long old = *address_as_ull;
    long assumed;

    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atom_cmpxchg(address_as_ull, assumed,
            as_long(val + as_double(assumed)));
        // Note: uses integer comparison to avoid hang in case of NaN (since NaN != NaN)
    } while (assumed != old);

    return as_double(old);
}
```

More details in the response of the post, thanks to @pmdj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 64-bit data (`double`), you will need to test for the [`cl_khr_int64_base_atomics`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_int64_base_atomics.html) extension. If your implementation supports that, you can use the `atom_cmpxchg()` function with `long`/`ulong` (64-bit integer) values.

For 32-bit `float`s, the [`atomic_cmpxchg` function](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomic_cmpxchg.html) is part of core OpenCL 1.2 and up. If your implementation only supports OpenCL 1.0, you will need to test for [the `cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics` extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics.html) and use its `atom_cmpxchg()` function if supported.

Treating the binary representation of a floating-point value as an integer and vice versa is most readily done in OpenCL using the `as_typen` operator. (Alternatively you are permitted to use `union` types for this, though that's not helpful in this case; for details see section 6.2.4 of the OpenCL specification.) In your code, the equivalent of `__double_as_longlong` would be `as_long()`, and instead of `__longlong_as_double` you would use `as_double()`.

Comment: thanks for response, Is it no longer necessary to do some kind of conversion like in the example with `__double_as_longlong` or `__longlong_as_double`?

Comment: @4lrdyD You do need to perform reinterpreting conversions, yes. In OpenCL, the equivalents of the ones you mention are `as_long()` and `as_double()`. See section 6.2.4 of the OpenCL specification for details.

Comment: I managed to write an equivalent to the original code thanks to your help, I will integrate it in the original publication, it seems to work, although it does not allow me to keep the name of the function as `atom_add`, any other suggestion would be welcome. thanks.

Comment: @4lrdyD Glad you got it working! `atom_add` is the name of a built-in function in OpenCL, so that would be why you can't use that name for your own function.